# Passing select id and value from HTML to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a simple program in JavaScript - k20 dice calculator. 
User can choose how many dice he wishes to throw, by HTML select :

```
<select id="kamount">
  <option value="1" id="id1"> k20</option>
  <option value="2" id="id2">2k20</option>
  <option value="3" id="id3">3k20</option>
  <option value="4" id="id4">4k20</option>
</select>
```

I want to pass the selection value to JavaScript function, which looks like this:

```
function dice_k20(dice){
  if (dice == 1){
    document.write(Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1));
  }
  else if (dice == 2) {
    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
      document.write(Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1));
    }
  }
  else if (dice == 3) {
    {
      for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        document.write(Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1));
      }
    }
    else if (dice == 4) {
      {
        for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
          document.write(Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1));
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I've been trying to pass the select value to the function, but it still doesn't work. The JS source code is in another file.

Thank you for help

Comment: Is dice a string or int?

Comment: how are you trying to pass the value? You're missing that part of the code

Comment: Is application listening for change event on select element or is user selecting a value then clicking e.g. button?

Comment: <select onclick="dice_k20(this.value)">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your javascript file refer in your html document.
**Else**
Edit your javascript code like this(keep your **dice_k20()** function)

```
var dice_val = document.getElementById('kamount').value;
dice_k20(dice_val);
```

Comment: <script src ="your_js_file.js"></script> in your html head